# Spark double type addition/subtraction bug

Tags: apache-spark

This has to be a known issue, but I can't find anything on it:

```
spark.sql("""
 select 48.85 + 6.95 + -55.80 x, 
        '48.85' + '6.95' + '-55.80' y,
        cast('48.85' as double) + cast('6.95' as double) + cast('-55.80' as double) z
""").show()
```

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|   x|                   y|                   z|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|0.00|7.105427357601002...|7.105427357601002...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I'm on AWS EMR spark 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually not the `7.10...` but `7.10... E-15`.

```
val df = spark.sql("""
 select 48.85 + 6.95 + -55.80 x, 
        '48.85' + '6.95' + '-55.80' y,
        cast('48.85' as double) + cast('6.95' as double) + cast('-55.80' as double) z
""")
df.printSchema()
df.show(false)

root
 |-- x: decimal(6,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- y: double (nullable = true)
 |-- z: double (nullable = true)

+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|x   |y                    |z                    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|0.00|7.105427357601002E-15|7.105427357601002E-15|
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As you know, it is coming from the double type precision. If you want to exact value, then use `decimal` type such as the column `x`.

Comment: Ah, tricked by truncate. Double precision, should call it double estimation. I'll stick with decimal. Thanks so much for shedding light on my misunderstanding.